# What is the point of bitwise and-ing with 255 when using bitshifting method of bytes reordering?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, byte, endianness

There is [an article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-endianc/), explaining little/big-endian topic, and it contains an example of endianness conversion function:

```
short reverseShort (short s) {
    unsigned char c1, c2;

    if (is_bigendian()) {
        return s;
    } else {
        c1 = s & 255;
        c2 = (s >> 8) & 255;

        return (c1 << 8) + c2;
    }
}
```

I understand, why they and-ing here:

```
c1 = s & 255;
```

`255` = `11111111`, so bitwise and with `s` which may be like `1011011010010010`, will not affect numbers in last 8 places, but turn all leading places to zeroes. So it's cuts bits to ending 8.

I also understand, why they using right shift here:

```
c2 = (s >> 8) & 255;
```

Shift by 8 cuts last 8 bits, so leading 8 remains. So in the first operation they get last 8 bits, and then first 8 bits.

But why they 'and'-ing it with `255` again?

Comment: If it weren't for the use of `unsigned char`, the masking would be to ensure that sign bits aren't mispropagated in the result.  Given that the code is using `unsigned char`, the only protection I can see is if `CHAR_BIT > 8` (or from a buggy compiler); otherwise, it gains nothing.  (You might need to check what GCC says at excruciatingly high warning levels since you're assigning a signed 16-bit value to an 8-bit unsigned variable on the typical computer.  The mask might quell a complaint.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `short` is not guaranteed to be 16-bit wide

Comment: @ouah: that's why I said _typical_.

Comment: @cad: you'd have to ask the code writer.  If the system was a 36-bit computer (such things used to exist) with `CHAR_BIT == 9`, then maybe the code is intended to map the value to a 16-bit value, instead of 18-bits.  The comments don't say "why"; the code doesn't say "why".  The GCC warning-suppression is semi-plausible; I've done similar things on occasion for that reason.  Otherwise, on a wide range of orthodox modern platforms, it doesn't help, as the OP suggested by asking about the issue.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I didn't want to sound too picky but you mentioned *the only protection I can see is if CHAR_BIT > 8* I thought you may want to add `short` size in the precaution list of your comment:)

Comment: @ouah: OK; thanks for the concern.  The code only plays with the low-order 16 bits of the (signed) `short` that is passed in, even if the type is longer than 16 bits.  The final return constructs the value from pieces, not by modifying the input value directly.  So, if `short` is longer than 16 bits, the code swaps the least significant 16 bits of the value in two 8-bit chunks and returns that 16-bit value as if it were a `short`.  That becomes a problem in the definition (description) of what the code does.

Comment: Why they use `unsigned char`, but not `unsigned short` for the result?

Comment: That is one of the minor mysteries of life — we can't tell what they writers of your article were thinking.  They wouldn't be the first (or last) people to write imperfect code that is subsequently published.  Presumably, they use `short` because the parameter of the function is `short`, and they want to write: `short s0 = …some value…; s0 = reverseShort(s0);` to reverse the bytes.  If it returned an `unsigned short`, a fussy compiler might complain about an unsigned-to-signed conversion, or something similar.

Comment: The correct way would be to cast both line to `unsigned char`. And you better should use fixed size-types `uint8_t` and `uint16_t`, etc. If enabled recommended warnings, your compiler should complain about the assignments without cast.

Answer (score 4):

lets say s = `binary representation: abcdefghijklmnopqrst`

```
c1 = s & 255; // < mnopqrst first 8 bits
c2 = (s >> 8) & 255;  //    from abcdefghijklmnopqrst >> 8 = abcdefghijkl & b11111111 = efghijkl

return (c1 << 8) + c2; // < (mnopqrst00000000) + efghijkl = mnopqrstefghijkl
```

its essentially taking the first 8 bits, and the next 8, then reverses them

> But why they 'and'-ing it with 255 again?

Thats to truncate it down to 8 bits if its longer

Comment: But the assignment to `c2` inherently truncates it to 8 bits when `CHAR_BIT == 8` (which is the most common value that most people encounter).

Comment: I guess it's just a more explicit conversion because `s` is still a short before the `&`

Comment: Actually, `short` is converted to `int` before the shift, but yes, `s >> 8` is longer than `unsigned char` on most CPU types.

Answer (score 2):

The problem stems from `s` being a *signed* short. If `s` has a negative value, then `s >> 8` causes implementation-defined behaviour.

Usually, implementations define that in this case bits shifted in from the left get filled with `1`. So the result of `10000000 00000000` shifted 8 to the right will be `11111111 10000000`, on those implementations.  Now, applying `& 255` will turn that into `00000000 10000000`, the desired result.

As has been noted in comments, (assuming 8-bit chars and 2's complement arithmetic) converting to `unsigned char` has the same effect as `& 255`. Since the result is being stored in an `unsigned char`, the `& 255` is redundant given those assumptions.

Another way to write this code, without relying on implementation-defined behaviour, would have been:

```
(unsigned short)s >> 8
```

Unsigned types always fill with zeroes when right-shifted.

A better way all round would be if the function both accepted and returned `unsigned short`. As it stands, `return (c1 << 8) + 2` either causes undefined or implementation-defined behaviour if the returned value is greater than `SHRT_MAX`.